# Can't install libwdi on windows

Tags: opos

I am trying to run the `escpos` javasript package ([escpos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos)) but can't install this `libwdi` thing. After downloading it and unrar it there is no intstallable file. Only bash files (`.sh`) and `.c` files. This is what is in the `libwdi.tar.gz`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should see README.md.
The installation / compile procedure, usage, FAQ are described in the following URL.

Installation and Compilation
See: https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/Install

API usage
See: https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/Usage

FAQ
See: https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/FAQ

The homepage of the above explanation is here.
https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki

In these explanations, source code is supposed to be compiled, but there are already install packages, which are distributed on the following pages.

[Zadig | USB driver installation made easy](https://zadig.akeo.ie/)

Download
Updated 2018.07.26:
[Zadig 2.4](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/releases/download/b721/zadig-2.4.exe) (4.9 MB)

If you can not install with this installation package or if the driver does not work, please follow the instructions on the explanation page above.